# LAN card not working sometimes with windows

Tags: windows-7, router, lan, network-adapter

I have the following scenario

```
MODEM +  (FE)(Cable A) --> (WAN) ROUTER (LAN)-----(FE)Cable B----COMPUTER
```

Now i have two LAN cards on computer

```
1)CARD A is build in Motherbord
2)CARD B is NIC Realteck in PCI Slot
```

Now

```
1)If i Plug Cable B in Card A then internet works fine
2)If i plug Cable B in CARD then it does not show anything. Says cable unplugged
```

then

```
1)If i put Cable A in CARD A or Card B then internet always works on both
```

I tried changing cables but same result

What can be the problem

Comment: What connection speeds are you seeing with Card A? Could it Cable B is defective and throttling the speeds on Card A, but Card B is just being proactive and refusing connection?

Comment: I tried chnaging ables as well so cable is not problem. Also CARD B works if connected directly from modem. How can i check speed

Comment: Have you tried selecting different speeds on the Realtek NIC?  IE if you have it set to AutoDetect currently, try setting it to Full Duplex and if that does not work, try Half Duplex.  Sometimes the autonegotiation protocol that the port is using to set that speed is not compatible with the protocol on the device at the other end and in such cases manually setting it to the correct setting can be all you need.

Comment: i tried setting full duplex and half as well but it didn't work

Comment: Well 105919... I am sorry.  I really expected that to work for you.  Aside from those options... at this point the only things I can think of are seeing if the router maybe has a firmware update out there of if perhaps the NIC does.  Barring that... all I can suggest is to keep trying different speed and negotiation settings.  I know my Intel LOM has about 6 seperate settings... try 'em all if you have more than Full Duplex and Half Duplex... :(